# HDR wide dynamic range of a moving subject?

Tags: filters, hdr, dynamic-range

I see many questions without any innovative answers to this problem. It is difficult to manually edit out the ghosts in Photoshop. A single RAW image is wonderful, comparing dynamic range to a single jpg and processed in Photomatix. But it does not compare to 5 well spaced jpgs. Or multiple RAWs. The goal is to capture extreme wide dynamic ranges of light and dark colors in the same image.

Can you think of an innovative way to achieve this with a fast moving subject?

Comment: _I see another question without any innovative answers to this problem._ Which question are you referring to?

Comment: There are a few I forgot which ones I’ve read. Search bar at the top type: HDR moving

Comment: Please don't tell me to search, in order to find what you're talking about. I'm not a mind-reader. I asked because I wonder if your question has essentially already been asked before.

Comment: There were many without new solutions I read everyone I could find.

Comment: Understood. But it would be helpful for readers if you pointed to questions that you read, and still didn't answer your question. It shows your research effort, and helps answerers possibly clarify misunderstandings or resources you might have missed, if that might be the case. =)

Answer (score 2):

It is impossible to extend the recorded DR of a single image beyond what the sensor is natively capable of (other than using the graduated ND previously noted in the other post).

It is possible to bracket exposures extremely quickly with some cameras (e.g. @ 20fps), which may be suitable for slow moving subjects... especially if you composite in a single frame of the critical sharp areas. But probably not suitable for fast moving subjects.

It may be possible to choose a camera that is capable of recording a greater DR. And it may also be possible to manipulate the recorded DR/capability to make use of tones that are otherwise typically under used/emphasized. E.g. with intentional underexposure and recovery in post (particularly useful with more ISO invariant cameras). But those are your only options.

Comment: You said these are the ONLY options. But you intentionally or unintentionally failed to mention the other paths I stated below. These have proven to work.

Comment: @SteveBright; no, I didn't. Highlight priority and ML's dual ISO are both forms of underexposing and recovery. Filters do not compress/extend the DR (they shift or reduce it). And higher ISO images necessarily mean less DR, because you cannot collect as much light.

Comment: You didn’t fail to mention? Or you claim I cannot capture more range? These 2 methods effectively use 2 different ISO’s or shutter speeds quickly in succession. Like exposure bracketing. I think you failed to understand the code I wrote for Dual ISO.

Comment: @SteveBright, the code you wrote? ML's Dual ISO uses line skipping to underexpose lines at a low ISO (to retain highlights) and uses a higher ISO for alternating lines (to recover shadows). This is no different from the underexposure/recovery I mentioned; except that it is better for non-ISO invariant cameras. It is not exposure bracketing because it does not change the amount of light recorded/recordable, nor the sensor's DR capability. Nikon's Highlight priority mode is also just underexposure. I think you fail to understand digital exposure.

Comment: As you said: For non ISO invariant cameras, it is exactly the same as using multiple ISOs for exposure bracketing!

Comment: Quick note. Most cameras are non ISO invariant so you’re just making up words.

Comment: Please do not refer to other posts it is forbidden by the rules. @Steven Kersting

Comment: Reading more. Very few cameras are absolutely invariant like Fuji. Some are nearly or partially. This matters.

Answer (score -2):

A single RAW. I have tried using a physical filter that compresses the dynamic range of the light before it reaches the sensor. This has given me an extra stop of range. It only helps when you can do this without increasing the iso beyond 200. Otherwise you lose the range you gained.

Highlight tone priority which simulates 2 exposures together for a fast moving subject. Minimize the contrast. Jpg only.

Dual ISO in magic lantern. The reduced resolution is minimal. It works even with a literal speeding bullet.

What kinds or types of filters compress the dynamic range?

To allow for an extended range HDR using Photomatix and a fast moving subject.

When the subject is black and the background is light, it is easy to remove the ghosting, as there is none, in at least one of the images.

I can see that it does not help to compress the range of a jpg. As you lose data. You can see the difference in the details of the image.

Using NEAT to process a higher ISO and retain sharpness. This seems to help improve the signal to noise ratio marginally. Combine with an ND filter.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135977/discussion-on-answer-by-steve-bright-hdr-wide-dynamic-range-of-a-moving-subject).